# How do I export tables from redshift into Parquet format?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, parquet

Couple of options I can think of

- Spark streaming back into s3 using Redshift connector
- UNLOAD into S3 gzipped then process with a command line tool

Not sure which is better. I'm not clear on how to easily translate the redshift schema into something parquet could intake but maybe the spark connector will take care of that for me.

Comment: Why do you want to stream from redshift ? exporting is usually a batch operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Redshift JDBC jar and use the `sparkSession.read.jdbc` with the redshift connection details like this in my example:

```
val properties = new java.util.Properties() 
properties.put("driver", "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver") 
properties.put("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshift-host:5439/") 
properties.put("user", "&lt;username&gt;") properties.put("password",spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.password", "&lt;default_pass&gt;")) 
val d_rs = spark.read.jdbc(properties.get("url").toString, "data_table", properties)
```

My relevant blog post: http://garrens.com/blog/2017/04/09/connecting-apache-spark-to-external-data-sources/

Spark streaming should be irrelevant in this case.

I would also recommend using databricks spark-redshift package to make the bulk unload from redshift and load into spark much faster.

Answer (score 4):

Spark is not needed anymore. We can unload Redshift data to S3 in Parquet format directly. The sample code:

```
UNLOAD ('select-statement')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
FORMAT PARQUET
```

You will be able to find more at [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)